# Why the newline is parsed as a child in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have found this weird behavior of `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html_doc1 = """<h1>test1</h1><h1>test2</h1>"""
>>> html_doc2 = """<h1>test1</h1>\n<h1>test2</h1>"""
>>> soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_doc1, 'html.parser')
>>> soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_doc2, 'html.parser')
>>> print(len(list(soup1.children)), len(list(soup2.children)))
2 3
```

Why is newline being pasred as a child?

I am expecting the empty line to be omitted.

Comment: Because it's a text node? Why wouldn't it be parsed?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-down):

> Tags may contain strings and other tags. These elements are the tag’s children. Beautiful Soup provides a lot of different attributes for navigating and iterating over a tag’s children.

---

If you like to exlude the `NavigableString` and only want to select direct descendants `tags`, you could use `recursive` here:

```
soup2.find_all(recursive=False)
```

In addition, there is no need to convert the `ResultSet` into `list`:

```
print(len(soup1.find_all(recursive=False)),len(soup2.find_all(recursive=False)))
```